# How do you zoom in/out inside an app on ARC welder?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

APK is installed and game is working. How do you zoom in or out inside the app?

Answer (score 0):

For most apps the answer will be "you cant", especially if you are not using a touchscreen Chromebook. One way around this for developers, would be to add zoom functionality by handling KeyEvents.

I am unsure if there is a way to programmably catch chromebook gestures in android code.